# Refreshing the template from an async update event in RiotJS

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I use [RiotJS](https://riot.js.org) for my template tags and I'm having a hard time with the following example:

Parent component:

```
<button onclick={ this.showUser } value="123">Chuck</button>
<button onclick={ this.showUser } value="456">John</button>

<user-card user-id={ this.userId }></user-card>

<script>
  this.showUser = (event) => {
    this.userId = event.target.value
  }
</script>
```

*user-card* component:

```
<user-card>
  <p>Welcome { this.user.firstname }</p>

  <script>
    this.on('mount', this.update)

    this.on('update', async () => {
      const response = await request(`http://localhost:3579/user/${this.opts.userId}`)
      this.user = response.data  // response.data: { "firstname": "Chuck" }
      this.update()  // Refresh the template
    })
  </script>
</user-card>
```

The `update()` method is automagically called by Riot.
Riot updates the template after the `on('update')` is called.
As my method is asynchronous, I must manually refresh the template calling `this.update()`.

**Issue:** calling `this.update()` also calls `on('update')` and is therefore recursing.

I could probably go with a *flag*, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant/convenient way to do this with Riot (like updating only the template without calling the `on('update')` again).

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your example I guess you can move the code that you are updating to a child component and update only the child, like this:

```
<user-card>
  <user-card-message message={ this.user.firstname }></user-card-message>

  <script>
    this.on('mount', this.update)

    this.on('update', async () => {
      const response = await request(`http://localhost:3579/user/${this.opts.userId}`)
      this.user = response.data  // response.data: { "firstname": "Chuck" }
      this.tags['user-card-message'].update()  // Refresh the template
    })
  </script>
</user-card>
```

Comment: That would do the job indeed but this is a sample for an architecture for a whole project; therefore it would not be sain to make a child component everytime you need an async function.
I ended up creating https://github.com/polight/lego —a simple reactive riot like lib— that can handle basic things like this.